# Its correct to not include a dependency on purpose on useEffect to avoid re-renderes when using react-route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my case here, I want to avoid the component `<Checkout/>` from re-rendering once I replace the url `props.history.replace(props.match.path + '/contact-data'` to load the `component` `<ContactData/>`.

As it can be seen on `useEffect` when `<Checkout/>` loads it gets a `query` tail on the `url`, something like this: `http://localhost:3000/checkout?cheese=0&salad=0&special=0&veggie=1`. Then I redirect to the url, having it like this: `http://localhost:3000/checkout/contact-data`, which renders `<ContactData/>` below , having both `<Checkout/>` & `<ContactData/>` on the screen.

My question is regarding `useEffect`. If I add a `props.location.search` as a dependency of `useEffect`, useEffect will cause a re-render of `<Checkout/>`, acting somehow like `ComponentDidUpdate` every time `props.location.search` changes.

On this use case, when I replace the `url` in order to load `<ContactData/>`, `props.location.search` will change and `<Checkout/>` would re-render if I had the dependency added, as explained above.

Now, I solved this behaviour by not adding the dependency to `useEffect` and still leaving the `array` of `deps` empty, forcing `useEffect` to run just once. Is this a bad practice? Would there be a proper way of doing this without cheating on `useEffect`?

```
useEffect(() => {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
        const ingredients = {};
        for (let param of query.entries()) {
            ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1]
        }
            setNewOrder(ingredients)
    },[props.location.search])
```

Even using `useEffect` with an empty `array` of `dependencies` I notice that the `<Checkout/>` still re-renders, but off course, not running the code inside `useEffect` on this new `render` cycle.

Would it be possible to really avoid `<Checkout/>` from re-rendering here?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, Fragment, Suspense} from 'react'
import {withRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutSummary from "../../components/CheckoutSummary/CheckoutSummary";
const ContactData = React.lazy(() => import("./ContactData/ContactData"))

function Checkout(props) {
    const [newOrder, setNewOrder] = useState(null);
    const returnToOrderCreationHandler = () => {
        props.history.goBack()
    }

    const confirmOrderHandler = () => {
        props.history.replace(props.match.path + '/contact-data')
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
        const ingredients = {};
        for (let param of query.entries()) {
            ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1]
        }
            setNewOrder(ingredients)
    },[])
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <CheckoutSummary ingredients={newOrder}
                             cancelCheckout={returnToOrderCreationHandler}
                             confirmCheckout={confirmOrderHandler}/>
            <Route path={props.match.path +  '/contact-data'} render={() =>
                <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}><ContactData/></Suspense>}/>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Checkout)
```

Comment: Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902 This should answer your query in detail

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for your comment. Well, I am kind of aware of those examples. If I use a callBack it would still not work, as the component would have to re-render a second time when I redirect and props.location.search would trigger a change inside useCallback. I guess that the only clean way would be to set the dependency ```props.location.search``` inside useEffect and then add a ```if``` statement  wrapping the whole block of code inside ```useEffect``` stating: ```if(props.location.search.length > 0) {...get the query and setState}...```

Comment: As this component only gets this query once the order is made in the app, there would be no risk in getting other stuff inside ```props.location.search``` creating some further conflict in this code. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the warning is there to notify the developer in case he/she is making an unknown error, However you must note that you might want to run the effect when search changes to reflect the update in data so think about it before you remove it from the dependency

Comment: Yep I see what you are saying. I actually will look for updates in whatever is received in ```props.location.search``` in this case, as no more ```queries``` will be passed to this component before I do not need it anymore. So if <Checkout/> were to be a ```class``` based ```component``` I would not use ```componentDidUpdate``` for this ```prop```. I would have this code set in ```componentDidMount``` to run it once and that is it. You see what I am saying?

Comment: So I am really aware of the behaviour that I want it to have, regarding the ```state``` updates. My big question here is about syntax, best practices, in a specific case like this one.

Comment: In such a case yes, you can disable the warning and allow the hook to execute when you want it to

Comment: Oh I see. Its cleaner than running an ```if``` statement to preserve the logic from re-running. I was just worried that the syntax where I would leave the dependency array empty could be seen as a bad practice or something of this sort

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution below a hack or a good practice in this case? Considering the idea behind the code, regarding the apps desired behaviour. Or could I keep the dependency array empty in `useEffect` as I do not want it to re-render, and then ignore the `eslint` error?

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if(props.location.search.length > 0) {
            const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
            const ingredients = {};
            for (let param of query.entries()) {
                ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1]
            }
            setNewOrder(ingredients)
        }
    },[props.location.search])
```

`<Checkout/>` cycle:

- 1st Render - `newOrder` is initialized as `null`
- 2nd Render - `useEffect` is executed - `newOrder` is set to whatever is received through `props.location.search`
- 3rd Render - once executing the `function` `confirmOrderHandler` the `url` changes `props.match.path + '/contact-data'`. `useEffect` recognizes a change through its dependency `props.location.search`, but before executing the code in its block again it checks if there is still a `string` at `props.location.search`, which in this case it will not be true, as we have replaced the `url`, so the logic is not re-executed and `state` is preserved.